# Mostrar resultado de un archivo PHP en HTML

Tags: php, html

Estoy trabajando con una API y tengo el siguiente codigo en php

```
<?php
$link = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=APIKEY&SteamID=STEAMID64&format=json');

$myarray = json_decode($link, true);

$count = 0;

foreach($myarray['result']['items'] as $item)
{
    if($item['defindex'] == 5021)
    { 
            $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
?>
```

Lo que esto hará sera arrojarme un valor numérico que yo deseo mostrarlo en una celda de una tabla. A diferencia de otros archivos php que pueden ejecutarse al hacer click en un botón yo necesito que el resultado que mi php arroja se demuestre apenas se carga la pagina.

Comment: A que te refieres con: necesito que el resultado que mi php arroja se demuestre apenas se carga la pagina. ??

Comment: Cuando tu entras por ej a una pagina de computacion puedes ver el stock de los productos sin la necesidad de apretar un boton. El stock se muestra apenas ingresas a la pagina. Eso mismo es lo que necesito.

Comment: Puedes usar javascript para cargar el resultado de un script en PHP, en una página que solo es html (más javascript, obvio). Eso es lo que se conoce como AJAX ¿es algo así lo que deseas hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que he podido observar, el objetivo es que por cada producto que tienes en tu tienda, deseas mostar la información del stock (cantidad total de productos) que se obtiene a través de la api. Manejan una serie de inconvenientes sobre si mostrar el resultado en un archivo html o en un archivo php.

Si es php, el script puede ejecutarse más rápido haciendo una llamada a una una función que cuente los items, por ejemplo podrías tener una función así:

```
   function contar_item($param, $array){
      $count = 0;
      foreach($myarray['result']['items'] as $item){
         if($item['defindex'] == $param){ 
           $count++;
         }
       }
       return $count;
    }
```

Y cuando se vaya ejecutando el script php se llame a dicha función, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i<$array_local; $i++){
     echo "<a href='#' class='item' data-id='".$i."'> ".contar_item($i,$array)." </a>";
    }
?>
```

Nótese que $array_local puede ser como tal un entero, o un array. Si es un array puedes usar el foreach y utilizar los índices para los parámetros.

Si es html, se debe hacer una llamada ajax por cada item y pasar como parámetro el identificador del producto (o el valor que represente el número "5021" en tu código). Si este es el caso, el foreach deberá hacerce desde javascript, por ejemplo utilizando jquery, tendrías algo como esto:

```
$( "a.item" ).each(function() {
  var id_item = $(this).data('item');
  var node = $(this);
   $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"llamadaAPI.php",
            data:"item="+id_item,
            success: function(data){$(node).html(data);}
        });
});
```

llamadaAPI.php recibirá un POST llamado item, que se tendrá que usar como parámetro de búsqueda. Al final se deberá imprimir el contador.

Esto dando por hecho de que la api no acepte más parámetros de filtrado, ya que por lo que he trabajado con este tipo de respuestas, se les puede enviar más parámetros de filtrado. Algo como esto:

http://miweb.com/parametro1/parametro2/

Donde parametro1 puede ser el catálogo, y parámetro2 el id del producto.

En este útlimo caso, si deseas hacer la respuesta menos pesada, te recomiendo que secciones el total de productos, y ya sea que vayas cargando más automáticamente al hacer un scroll, pongas un botón de "cargar más", o utilices paginación.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tienes un archivo index.php creado, funcionando en un servidor que soporte php, luego ejecuta ese archivo en el navegador y se te mostrará automaticamemente, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
//El siguiente array simula la llamada al api que mencionas.
$myarray = array(
                 "result" => 
                        array( "items"=>
                                array(1,2,3)
                             ) 

                );

//Aqui genero una tabla para mostrar los datos del arreglo, 
//esto lo puedes editar a tu conveniencia.
$table = "<table border='1'>";
$table .= "<tr>";
$table .= "<th>Item nro</th>";
$table .= "</tr>";
foreach($myarray['result']['items'] as $item)
{   
    $table .= "<tr>";
    $table .= "<td>$item</td>";
    $table .= "</tr>";

}

$table .= "<table border='1'>";

echo $table;
?>
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Importa el código de la ‘función php’ la cual arroja el valor que deseas mostrar en tu otro archivo donde desees mostrarlo.

```
use /* Aquí va la dirección de tu archivo con la función. */
```

Simplemente para mostrar el valor, usa la función `echo` que provee php.

Es importante recalcar que **no hay forma de ejecutar código PHP en un archivo HTML**, a menos que estés usando un sistema de plantillas como Blade.

Comment: Seria algo asi?:

use ../php/items.php

Y luego en donde quiera mostrarlo simplemente pongo <?php echo $count ?> ?

Comment: Exactamente, recuerda que el archivo donde deseas mostrar ese resultado debe tener por igual extensión .php para que pueda ser interpretado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En un archivo html sería imposible mostrar el resultado.

Tendrías que pasar tu archivo .html a .php y al principio de este hacer un include.

```
<?php    
include('tufuncion.php');
?>
```

Así tu tu index.php cargaría tu función del api y solo tendrías que abrir etiquetas de php y hacer un echo en la celda donde quieras mostrar el número.

Si no quisieras pasar el archivo a .php creo que solo te quedaría la opción de hacerlo con ajax.

Comment: Comprendo. Ahora si yo tuviera que contar mas de un item tendría que hacer cientas de mi función (Una para cada item) que me arroja el resultado en el index.php y estaría bastante cargado. Por eso pensé que de alguna forma podría traerlo y mostrarlo en mi index.html.

Comment: Igualmente si lo haces en un index.html y llamar a php por ajax el numero de funciones de php van a seguir siendo las mismas, y el tiempo de ejecución incluso mayor al meter javascript de por medio.

Comment: Ya veo. Entonces cual crees que seria la forma mas efectiva de mostrar el stock de mas de 200 productos llamados mediante una api? Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Nose si tienes pensado hacer una función para cada producto por lo que entiendo, o si todos los productos están en la misma tabla.   Yo lo estructuraría de la siguiente manera.  Primero haces una consulta que saque todos los datos del producto con una sola consulta.  La consulta te devuelve un array con todos los productos, en ese momento recorres el array y creas la tabla a la par que integras los datos en ella misma.